# Java: Interface generic of a superclass

Tags: java, generics, interface

Imagine the following code:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

interface IA extends Iterable<A> {}
interface IB extends Iterable<B> {}
```

Ideally, I would like the interface `IB` to be able to also extend `IA` because it does in fact allow you to retrieve `A`s.

```
interface IB extends Iterable<B>, IA {}
```

or even

```
interface IB extends Iterable<B> implements IA {}
```

However, the compiler really dislikes both of those and it would make my code much better if this was allowed as conceptually B can be used as A without up-casting everywhere

What solutions are available for me to solve this problem?

Comment: It's difficult to see how this would be useful; could you add an example of how you'd like to **use** `IB`, assuming what you wanted were possible?

Comment: Big picture: `A` is a User and `B` is an Administrator. `IA` lists users from different source and IB lists Administrators form other sources. When I use `IB` I would like to also be able to pass it to functions who expect `IA`s because they are compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type cannot have two super types `G<X> and G<Y> where X!=Y` - probably due to erasure.

One way to solve your problem is to use a type parameter for the type to be iterated

```
interface IA<X extends A> extends Iterable<X>
{
    @Override Iterator<X> iterator();
}
interface IB extends IA<B>
{
    @Override Iterator<B> iterator();
}
```

I'd usually avoid that, it's just more complexity.

---

In your example, extending `Iterable<A>` is probably not a good idea in the first place. For example

```
class Team implements Iterable<Member>
{
    public Iterator<Member> iterator() { ... }
}

for(Member member : team) ...
```

but a team concept probably is broader than just a collection of members. It might be clearer to

```
class Team
{
    Iterable<Member> members() { ... }
}
for(Member member : team.members()) ...
```

In that case, your types can be designed as

```
interface IA
{
    Iterable<? extends A> members();
}

interface IB extends IA
{
    @Override
    Iterable<? extends B> members();
}
```

---

One can also question whether `Iterable` should have been more relaxing, instead of

```
public interface Iterable<T> 

    Iterator<T> iterator();
```

would it be better to

```
public interface Iterable<T> 

    Iterator<? extends T> iterator();
```

Comment: I don't think your solution will compile though, because you're changing the return type. Edit: nm, it works because of covariant return types, gotcha.

Comment: I'm choosing this solution because it was easy to integrate as well as working and clear.

Answer (score 9):

The [non-covariance of generics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) means that what you want isn't viable (at least not in the general case).

However, perhaps [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) would solve your specific problem?  e.g.

```
void methodThatOperatesOnA(Iterable<? extends A> it) {
    ...
}
```

This will allow you to extract elements from `it` as if they were `A`s, but the compiler will prevent you from inserting objects,<sup>*</sup> because it can't guarantee that invariants would be maintained.

---

<sub>* other than `null` <s>and a few other wacky cases</s></sub>

Comment: +1 This is wildcards at their best. Nitpick: what are these "few other wacky cases"? IIRC `null` covers it as far as what a producer can consume.

Comment: @PaulBellora: It's stuff to do with "wildcard capture".  So you can do things like `list.add(list.get(0))`.

Comment: Last time I checked you couldn't do that though - there's a post about it somewhere.

Comment: @PaulBellora: Ah, maybe you can't.  TBH, I've only read about it, I've never needed to do it in practice.

Comment: Yeah check out [`Collections.swap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.swap%28java.util.List%2Cint%2Cint%29) for a good example - a rawtype is used because of that limitation.

Comment: @PaulBellora it doesn't have to use raw type. `void swap(List<?> list){ swap2(list); }   <T> void swap2(List<T> list){ list.set(i, list.get(j)); } see example in JLS 5.1.10

Comment: @irreputable Yeah, you're right (though my point was only about wildcard capture).

Answer (score 1):

Generics in Java are not covariant -- that is, `List<String> instanceof List<Object>` is false. Thus, `IB` is **not** an instance of `IA` and hence is the cause of your compiler woes, I believe.

Imagine a new class, `class C extends A {}`. C IS-A A, and thus C would be a legitimate value for IA to contain -- but not for IB. Thus, if you tried to use IB as an instance of IA, you could insert a C and break the type-safety guarantees.

Comment: Yes. How do I work around it or provide a better API? I assumed this is the cause, the question is how to fix it.

Comment: I don't think there *is* a solution without nasty instanceof checks and casting.